# Is Monaco Diff Editor capable for Diff data format as input?

Tags: javascript, diff, monaco-editor

I'm referring to the Monaco Diff Editor: Just scroll down on: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html

As shown in the official code example (https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/browser-amd-diff-editor/index.html) the model expects two models as inputs: One model of the original data and one model of the data to be compared with:

```
            diffEditor.setModel({
                original: monaco.editor.createModel(originalTxt, 'javascript'),
                modified: monaco.editor.createModel(modifiedTxt, 'javascript'),
            })
```

My question is: Is it also possible to pass an already created diff instead of the original and modified data? Something like:

```
--- /srv/qc/reference.xml   2019-05-16 08:30:10.837000000 +0000
+++ /srv/qc/candidate.xml   2019-05-16 08:30:10.833000000 +0000
@@ -1,28 +1,28 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root-element xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com callback_reply.xsd">
   <reply>
     <status code="10301" severity="I" msg="DemoDCP called"/>
     <dataApp>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_CITY" f="X" v="Stuttgart"/>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_ZIP_CODE" f="X" v="70178"/>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_COUNTRY" f="X" v="Deutschland"/>
-      <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_GENDER" f="X" v="f"/>
+      <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_GENDER" f="X" v="m"/>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_PHONE" f="X" v="#PHONE Value#"/>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_FAX" f="X" v="#FAX Value#"/>
       <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_EMAIL" f="X" v="#EMAIL Value#"/>
-      <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_ROLE" f="X" v="VP2"/>
+      <var id="ZZ_ZZ_ZZ_TXV_CONTACT_ROLE" f="X" v="VP1"/>
     </dataApp>
   </reply>
 </root-element>
```

Comment: [VSCode doesn't have this functionality](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34623), so I don't think it's possible to directly do this with monaco-editor.

Comment: You could parse the diff file and get the before and after files, but what if some of the context is missing (not all lines are in the diff file)? What do you want the editor to show?

Comment: If you want, I [kind of have a partial solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/56183384-dvpzn?file=/src/index.ts). It uses [diff2html](https://diff2html.xyz/)'s `parse` function to parse the diff (it was the only maintained library with TypeScript typings I could find) and then converts the diff into the before and after strings. However, it just concatenates blocks, ignoring any skipped lines. Let me know if this is suitable and I'll turn this into a full answer.